# ECC Curve25519 KeyChain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, elliptic-curve, curve-25519

I'm trying to create Curve25519 keys using the KeyChain on iOS. I am aware of the existence of CryptoKit, unfortunately, that is not available for iOS 12. Is there a way to create a Curve25519 key pre CryptoKit, maybe a parameter I'm missing when generating it in the KeyChain? The code below will only generate the P-256 keys.

```swift
let attributes: [String: Any] = [
    String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey,
    String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): 256
]

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
print(privateKey ?? error!.takeUnretainedValue())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's old core crypto lib `CommonCrypto` doesn't support modern curves like `curve25519` and quite frankly is a total mess, littered with insecure ciphers, they aren't even clear on the actual curve equations being used.

Additionally, although `CryptoKit` supports `curve25519` for key exchange, it's still limited, for example, you cannot use the "Secure Enclave" to generate `curve25519` keys, only `P-256`, which is likely backdoored (just look at the curve co-efficients), despite all financial institutions seemingly loving it.

Ultimately a `curve25519` private key is just a large (`2^256`) number (though it is "clamped" before use), so if you just need to generate keys, you can do this with `SecRandomCopyBytes`.

Though, if as I suspect you want to do some `X25519` KEX or `EdDSA` signature over `25519`, then just use `libsodium`. It's the goto library for `NaCl`, there is a [really great](https://github.com/jedisct1/swift-sodium) interface in `Swift` written by the original `libsodium` author, called `swift-sodium`, I've used it and it's great. **It also supports iOS 12+.**

Generating keys in `libsodium` for `curve25519` is as simple as:

```
import Sodium

let sodium = Sodium()
let curve25519KeyPair = sodium.box.keyPair()
let privateKey = curve25519KeyPair!.secretKey
let publicKey = curve25519KeyPair!.publicKey
```

You can then manually store in KeyChain.

Shout if you need further help, and good choice using `25519`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shame there is no native support pre iOS 12 from Apple. I agree on the mess of the CommonCrypto library. Well, I guess that leaves me no other choice but to use some external project such as libsodium!

Comment: You’re very welcome @Bram, HMU if you have any extra questions.

Comment: Any advice to add something [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/85831/18298) that I can find around officially?

Comment: "just look at the curve co-efficients"?

Comment: 41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291 vs 7